# CSS white-space: normal fails with sibling span element in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, word-wrap

I have encountered an issue when trying to restrict line wrapping to particular locations on lines. I know that there are other ways to do this, but the way that was simplest for me (with my generated HTML) was setting everything as `white-space: nowrap` and overriding this at some points with `white-space: normal`. In Firefox this was failing at some locations, seemingly only next to other spans. In Chrome it was working fine.

An example of the problem in Firefox:

```css
p {
    background: red;
    width: 40em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.allow-break {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<h3>With sibling span:</h3>
<p>
    Distinctio labore et unde veniam.
    Autem aut dolorum numquam ipsam. Amet impedit omnis
    <span class="allow-break"> </span>
    <span>span</span>
    quibusdam qui. Quo nemo qui nihil.
</p>
<h3>Without sibling span:</h3>
<p>
    Distinctio labore et unde veniam.
    Autem aut dolorum numquam ipsam. Amet impedit omnis
    <span class="allow-break"> </span>
    span
    quibusdam qui. Quo nemo qui nihil.
</p>
```

Is this a bug in Firefox, or just some ambiguity I am unaware of? It doesn't seem that a unstyled `span` should make any difference.

Comment: both code give the same result for me (Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Sure looks like a Firefox bug to me, too.

Comment: Different for me. Chrome 95, FF 94. (From the snippet.)